# Add link to the top menu of Modern Sites

Tags: current-navigation, modern-team-site

How to add a link to the top menu on a Modern Sites. I do have global admin permission, but don't see the edit button

Answer (score 1):

If you are refering to the Office 365 bar you will find the options in the Office 365 admin center under Settings - Organization profile (see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-office-365-theme-for-your-organization-8275da91-7a48-4591-94ab-3123a3f79530)